# Mysql query which returns category tree

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, categories

I am working on category management. Where i have parentId with each row. Categories can be n-level.
I can recursively call php function which will return category tree array.

[image]

Now Issue is: In admin panel i want category listing page as shown below. i.e. which category is under which.

- Home
- Products (Edit) (Delete)
- Products > Product 1 (Edit) (Delete)
- Products > Product 2 (Edit) (Delete)
- Products > Product 2 > Product 2 1 (Edit) (Delete)
- Products > Product 2 > Product 2 2 (Edit) (Delete)
- Contact Us (Edit) (Delete)

I want mysql query result in same order as shown above. I am not sure how can i achieve it.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_categories
ORDER BY ???
```

Please guide.

Comment: Better use for it server pgoramming languages.

Comment: It is working with programming. There can be paging in listing, i want to use limit with that query. Somewhere in shopping cart opensource i have seen, but i don't remember how they have done.

Comment: please show us the table structure, i.e. Lets say, i want 2 get the row Product 2.1

Comment: If needed i can add other field in table i.e. category_depth,..or any other. Which can be used in query.

Comment: What is the table structure? If you want this to be done in single query, you might need to change the way you store categories. See [`Modified Preorder Tree Traversal` algorithm](http://imrannazar.com/Modified-Preorder-Tree-Traversal) for instance.

Comment: @VibhaJ depth by itself does not give enough information... (there may be elements of same depth as children of different parents)

Comment: Updated question with table structure.

Comment: Ok, with current table structure, there is no single SQL query that can bring you a result ordered properly. Either use application logic with recursive calls to discover children on each level, or You will have to modify the table (see info above regarding MPTT)

Comment: Thanks for MPTT, i understood it, but when i am adding any new category to maintain this left, right MPPT value with php code will be difficult.

Comment: Maintaining those indexes is actually not that difficult. Two UPDATE queries are needed to make room for a new entry, and you can add them to a routine that does category creation.

Comment: And what are that 2 update  queries?

Comment: @poncha: there is no single **MySQL** query to do that. Most other DBMS do support recursive queries which could very well return that in a single query. But you are right that with MySQL this table structure is not a viable solution.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i think it would be a good idea to add an answer that provides sample solution for other DBMS then.. ? (Maybe someone will consider picking a different tool for the jobs then)

Comment: @poncha: this question comes up on SO about once a week there are many answers to this here (in fact I actually think this question can already be treated as a duplicate).

Comment: See this [slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) for various options on modelling hierarchical data and which models work better with which queries. On page 69, you'll see that the query you want (Query Subtree) is hard on the Adjacency List model you are using.

Answer (score 2):

There is no *single SQL query* that can bring You results ordered the way You expect based on this table structure.

There are two ways of solving the issue:

1. Use external application logic (outside of DB) to make recursive calls that will discover children of each category and build the tree in application.
2. Use one of the algorithms for storing tree data in a relational database.
   One of such algorithms is called [`Modified Preorder Tree Traversal`](http://imrannazar.com/Modified-Preorder-Tree-Traversal) or simply MPTT.

Assuming we use columns `lft` and `rgt` to maintain left / right indexes in traversal, when you insert a new category you will need to:

1. Get parent category info by Id: `SELECT lft,rgt FROM tbl_categories WHERE categoryId=5`
   Lets assume for a matter of example, that the parent category had `lft=7` and `rgt=10` (in this case it has one child already)
2. Make room for a new entry - shift all records by 2 (1 for lft and 1 for rgt):

   `UPDATE tbl_categories SET rgt=rgt+2 WHERE rgt>=10 ORDER BY rgt DESC`

   `UPDATE tbl_categories SET lft=lft+2 WHERE lft>=10 ORDER BY lft DESC`

Note here `ORDER` descending. As `lft` and `rgt` are supposed to be unique, it is advised to make a `UNIQUE` constraint on them, and then descending order in update is needed to prevent duplicate key errors.

1. Set `lft=<former parent rgt>` and `rgt=<former parent rgt +1>` and insert a new record...

   `INSERT INTO tbl_categories SET categoryName="New Child",parentCategoryId=5,lft=11,rgt=12,...`

You can find more detailed examples with code if you search for `MPTT PHP MySQL`. There are quite a few tutorials on this subject.

Comment: @VibhaJ: another option would be a closure table: http://karwin.blogspot.de/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html  which has the added benefit that you can have foreign keys to ensure that the parent category actually exists.

Comment: Btw, i usually use MPTT while still keeping parent (and i even add depth) in the table, then it doesnt have a pitfall of finding immediate relatives...

Comment: Closure model is more efficient than MPTT (also known as Nested Sets) model, I think, in most cases. Inserting and moving nodes around the tree structure needs less operations.

Comment: how about fetching the whole tree / subtree? MPTT does this easily with a plain select (without joins). Plus (IMHO) closure tables are harder to look at (for humans), since the main entity table loses any structural information and the relations table is not human readable by itself at all...

Answer (score 2):

you can use a stored function that will recursively fetch the root path and concatenate with your parent.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `get_category`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `get_category`(cat_id int) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE c_id INT;
DECLARE p_id INT;
DECLARE count INT;
DECLARE cat_name VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE cat_path VARCHAR(255);
set c_id = cat_id;
SELECT parent_category_id, category_name INTO p_id, cat_name FROM categories WHERE category_id = c_id;
set c_id = p_id;
set cat_path=cat_name;
set count=0;
WHILE (c_id IS NOT NULL) DO 

SELECT parent_category_id, category_name INTO p_id, cat_name FROM categories WHERE category_id = c_id;
set c_id = p_id;
set cat_path = concat_ws('>',cat_name,cat_path);
set count = count + 1;
IF count=10 THEN
  SET c_id = NULL;
END IF;
 END WHILE;
RETURN cat_path;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and then call using

```
select getcategory(category_id);
```

Herre in this function i have made a sanity check so as to avoid infinite looping..

Comment: This discovers path for a single category though, so if you're fetching a tree, this would require calling this for every result... But nice anyway ;)

Comment: its just a prototype, you can modify even this further to a procedure, with a cursor, and loops to each category tree.. and proceed on.. i believe it can be done

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this in a single mysql query.
Well you can achieve this, by executing multiple queries.
The algorithm goes like this :
Initially create a data set object which you will populate, by fetching data from the data base. 
Create a method which takes the parent id as parameter and returns its child nodes if present, and returns -1, if it doesnt have a child.
Step1: Fetch all the rows, which doesn't have a parent(root) node.
Step2: 
Iterate through this result.
For example if prod1 and prod2 are the initial returned nodes, in the resultset. Iterating this RS we get prod1, and we insert a row in our DataSET obj. Then we send the id of prod1 to getCHILD method, to get its child, and then again we iterate the returned resultset, and again call the  getCHILD method, till we dont get the lowest node.